# solc unable to import scoped packages

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solc

I am trying to import these lines on solidity and compile it with solc

```
import '@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol';
import '@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol';
```

Every time I run the compile.js I get this error.

```
{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"mysample.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source \"@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol\" not found: File import callback not supported\nimport '@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol';
\n^-------------------------------------------------------------------------^
\n","message":"Source \"@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol\" not found: File import callback not supported","severity":"error","sourceLocation":{"end":135,"file":"mysample.sol","start":60},"type":"ParserError"},
{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"mysample.sol:5:1: ParserError: Source \"@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol\" not found: File import callback not supported\nimport '@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol';
\n^-------------------------------------------------------------^
\n","message":"Source \"@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol\" not found: File import callback not supported","severity":"error","sourceLocation":{"end":200,"file":"mysample.sol","start":137},"type":"ParserError"}],"sources":{}}
```

The code for compile.js used

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const mysamplePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'mysample.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(mysamplePath, 'utf8');

console.log(solc.compile(
  JSON.stringify({
    language: "Solidity",
    sources: {
      "mysample.sol": {
        content: source
      }
    },
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        "*": {
          "*": ["evm", "bytecode"]
        }
      }
    }
  })
));
```

I have no idea why the compiler can not find the uniswap import. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you include the imports in the JSON imput to the compiler?

Comment: i did not, how it would look like when adding the imports?

Comment: I'll add `"<.sol path>": {
        content: <.sol content>
      }` to the sources section for every imported file.